# How to prevent user from resizing columns of QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I'd like to manage width of my columns in a table personally, but after resizing them from the code, I cannot figure out a way to prevent user from resizing them manually. I found out that `QTableView` has the `columnResized()` slot, and the only ways to do it I see are either subclassing `QTableWidget` or resizing columns again and again on the timer event.

Might there be an easier way?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It can be done using :

[`void QHeaderView::setSectionResizeMode (ResizeMode mode)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode) 
   [`void QHeaderView::setSectionResizeMode (int logicalIndex, ResizeMode mode)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode-2)

The horizontal header is reachable from a `QTableWidget` using `horizontalHeader()`.

This is it:

```
ui->tMeal->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode (QHeaderView::Fixed);
```

Note that legacy (Qt4) applications should use [`setResizeMode()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qheaderview-compat.html#setResizeMode).